# Asyncronous Google Analytics custom variables

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have a webpage with a 'Start test' button, I would like to track the value of an input: `<input id="RepeatsInput" type="text" />` every time the button is clicked through Google analytics - bearing in mind I am using Google analytics to track the pageviews (this will have happened already before the user presses the button). What snippet of code should I use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not known exactly how the HTML is set up, consider this example:

HTML:

```
<input id="RepeatsInput" type="text" />
<button onclick="setCustomVar();">Start test</button>​
```

JS:

```
function setCustomVar() {
   var inputValue = document.getElementById("RepeatsInput").value;
   _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'YOUR-CUSTOM-VAR-NAME', inputValue]);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
}
```

Google's documentation on [Custom Variables explains that another `_trackPageview` will need to be called for custom variables set by user events](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#recommended).

> **Call the _setCustomVar() function when it can be set prior to a pageview or event GIF request.**
>   In certain cases this might not be possible, and you will need to set another _trackPageview() request after setting a custom variable. This is typically only necessary in those situations where the user triggers a session- or visit-level custom var, where it is not possible to bundle that method with a pageview, event, or ecommerce tracking call.

[Event tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) may be another way to address this.

Comment: AFAIK event tracking is the usual way to address this. At least, I hope so... that's how I've always done it.

Comment: @GGG Right, I agree and I mentioned event tracking. But not knowing the OP's intentions, I didn't draw a hard line on the issue.

Comment: Fair enough. It's often a hard call to make around here. Help them do it the way they're doing it, or advise them to do it the "usual" way?

Comment: Thanks guys, I am always open to do something a different way if it's better - I am definitely going to use events so thanks for that JK. I never vote people's answers down if they suggest I am going down the wrong path - it's the advice I have come for!